# Parallel I/O queries with progress updates

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, asp.net-mvc-5, task-parallel-library

I've got an mvc5 controller which consumes two paged, remote data services. The two services must be called in series - when a page of data is returned from serviceA, it must be sent to serviceB. My naieve completely serial implementation looks like this:

```
var pageNumber = 1;
var totalPages = x;
var results = new List<ProcessedResult>();
do {
    // Get results from service A.
    var initialResults = await serviceA.GetDataPageAsync(pageNumber);

    // Send serviceA's results to service B
    var processedResults = await serviceB.ProcessAsync(initialResults );

    // Save this iteration's results to our result collection.
    results.AddRange(processedResults); 

    //Report our progress so far
    ReportProgress((float)(pageNumber/totalPages)*100);

} while (pageNumber<totalPages);

return View(results)
```

How would I start to query the "pages" in parallel (or asynchronously) without breaking the continuation (serviceB follows serviceA for each page) or the progress reporting? Thanks.

Comment: Extract the body of the loop to a separate `async` function, invoke it once for each page, collect the resulting tasks and `WaitAll` or `WhenAll` on them. As for reporting, don't send a percentage, send an increment and let the `ReportProgress` function calculate the percentage

Answer (score 2):

You can use TPL Dataflow for that. You create each block with its action and options (like `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`) and connect them together with `LinkTo`:

```
var aBlock = new TrasnformBlock<int, InitalResult>(
    pageNumber =>  serviceA.GetDataPageAsync(pageNumber),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5});
var bBlock = new TrasnformBlock<InitalResult, ProcessedResult>(async initialResult =>  
{
    var result = await serviceB.ProcessAsync(initialResult);
    // ReportProgress
    return result;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5});   

aBlock.LinkTo(bBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true })

for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < totalPages; pageNumber++)
{
    aBlock.Post(pageNumber);
}

aBlock.Complete();
await aBlock.Completion;
```